# mgwt custom styling

Tags: gwt, styling, mgwt

I am trying to use the custom styling as shown here (https://code.google.com/p/mgwt/wiki/Styling):

```
public class MGWTColorTheme implements MGWTTheme {

                private MGWTClientBundle bundle;

                public MGWTColorTheme() {
                        if (MGWT.getOsDetection().isIOs()) {
                                if (MGWT.getOsDetection().isRetina()) {
                                        bundle = (MGWTColorBundleRetina) GWT.create(MGWTColorBundleRetina.class);
                                } else {
                                        bundle = (MGWTColorBundleNonRetina) GWT.create(MGWTColorBundleNonRetina.class);
                                }
                        } else {
                                bundle = (MGWTColorBundleNonRetina) GWT.create(MGWTColorBundleNonRetina.class);
                        }

                }

                @Override
                public MGWTClientBundle getMGWTClientBundle() {
                        return bundle;
                }

        }
```

and

```
MGWTStyle.setTheme(new MGWTColorTheme());
```

When I load my app I get the following error:

```
Rebinding com.googlecode.mgwt.ui.client.theme.mgwt.MGWTColorBundleNonRetina
Invoking generator com.google.gwt.resources.rebind.context.InlineClientBundleGenerator
Creating assignment for getButtonBarCss()
Replacing CSS class names
The following unobfuscated classes were present in a strict CssResource:
text
Fix by adding String accessor method(s) to the CssResource interface for obfuscated classes, or using an @external declaration for unobfuscated classes.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like you are using a broken theme which has css classes present in the css files that are not declared in the java interfaces.

If you want to get started with mgwt styling you can easily clone the themebase project and start from there:

https://code.google.com/p/mgwt/source/checkout?repo=themebase